# Embeded script only running properly on second pageview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, squarespace

I am having a bit of my website only properly work whenever you visit the page the second time. 3 fields are not shown in the page the first time you view it, but after going to another section of the site and coming back, so long as you do not reload the page, the fields will properly display.

To reproduce the issue, go to http://imperialgaming.tech/.
Click on the Minecraft logo. Take note of the seemingly bad grammar in at the bottom of the area of text as the page tries to inform you about the status of the server. Now, click on the teamspeak logo at the bottom of the page, and then click again on the minecraft icon at the bottom of the page. You will now notice that the message at the bottom of the text has much better grammar, and more information to it. Refreshing the page resets this back to the broken version. You can find the code [here](http://pastebin.com/vXau8bqM). I apologize, squarespace breaks my indentation. Let me know if you have any idea what causes this or how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because the script is running before the elements have been created in the DOM. Try adding the script section after this div block instead of before it:

```
<div class="server-status">
  Our server is currently <span class="server-online"></span>!
  There are <span class="server-players"></span> of <span class="server-max-players"></span> online.
</div>
<script>
  MinecraftAPI.getServerStatus('mc.imperialgaming.tech', {
    port: 25565 // optional, only if you need a custom port
   }, function (err, status) {
     if (err) {
       return document.querySelector('.server-status').innerHTML = 'Error loading status';
     }
     document.querySelector('.server-online').innerHTML = status.online ? 'up' : 'down';
     document.querySelector('.server-players').innerHTML = status.players.now;
     document.querySelector('.server-max-players').innerHTML = status.players.max;
  });
</script>
```

### Updated

If within squarespace you are unable to move the script to be after (as I see that it is in the `<head>`) then try wrapping the entire code in jquery document ready block (this way the script will wait for the DOM to load) and use jquery selectors:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
  MinecraftAPI.getServerStatus('mc.imperialgaming.tech', {
    port: 25565 // optional, only if you need a custom port
   }, function (err, status) {
     if (err) {
       return document.querySelector('.server-status').innerHTML = 'Error loading status';
     }
     $('.server-online').innerHTML = status.online ? 'up' : 'down';
     $('.server-players').innerHTML = status.players.now;
     $('.server-max-players').innerHTML = status.players.max;
  });
});
</script>
```